# Shell Script for removing folder based on creation date

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I have folder names in the below date format

31082018 
04092018
01092018
05092018
02092018
03092018
06092018

Everyday the folder is created and the old ones get modified.
I am trying to find a unix script that would remove all folders execept the 3 newly created ones based on creation date.
If i am using `find . -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;` 
 its not helping me because  the older folder are getting modified and -mtime and -ctime treat them as the recent one.

For example, in the dates that I have mentioned above, except directory with names 04092018,05092018 and 06092018 all other should get deleted.

I am trying to use below script to get desire result but unable to substituent **$last** variable in below shell script

```
#! /bin/bash
last=$(date -d '-2 days' +%d%m%Y);
find /orabackup/RMAN/SYMETRA -type d -exec bash -c '
    cd ${1%/*}
    dir=${1##*/} day=${dir:0:2} month=${dir:2:2} year=${dir:4:4}
    [[ $dir =~ [0-9]{8} && $year$month$day <  $last ]] && echo rm -rf "$1"
' -- {} \;
```

Comment: The creation date is not stored in a directory entry. You have only the date of the last modification, and of the last inode change time. If you are happy with the latter, you can use `-ctime` instead of `-mtime`. Another possibility - since you seem to encode the creation date in the directory name - is to use the directory names for sorting the directories by date (which is a bit tricky with your naming schema, but still feasible).

Comment: I am trying to  use one shell script, but unable to substitute variable $last in that <br />#! /bin/bash
last=$(date -d '-2 days' +%d%m%Y);
find /orabackup/RMAN/SYMETRA -type d -exec bash -c '
    cd ${1%/*}
    dir=${1##*/} day=${dir:0:2} month=${dir:2:2} year=${dir:4:4}
    [[ $dir =~ [0-9]{8} && $year$month$day <  $last ]] && echo ls -ltr "$1"
' -- {} \;

Comment: The `$last` variable is enclosed in single quotes. It can't be substituted!

Comment: In addition, last contains the date in the form day-month-year, and you compare it to a string in the form year-month-day. This won't give a reasonable result.

Comment: @user1934428 so can u rectify and give me proper script please

Comment: Actually I overlooked that you wrote that you get one new directory EVERY day. In this case we don't of course need any sorting. We just need to calculate the names of the three directories in question: Today, yesterday, and the day before yesterday. See [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html) how this is done.

Comment: Seem you also need to put the `last=$(date -d '-2 days' +%Y%m%d);` inside the `-exec bash - c '...` otherwise the new bash instance won't know the `$last` variable.